# How to show PreferenceScreen within PreferenceFragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-preferences

I am new to android and I would appreciate your help. This is my first question =D Sorry for giving only two links and no images, I have not enought reputation to made my question more clear

Acording to [android API guides for settings](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings.html#PreferenceHeaders), I am using [PreferenceFragment](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceFragment.html) because I am developing for Android 3.0 (API level 11) and higher.

I want to achieve a effect as shown at figure 4 and 5 from android API guides for settings link.

On tablet emulator it looks ok, but on handset emulator (and real device) I can not achieve it. Instead I get "Sound", "Display", "Storage", "Battery"... as PreferenceCategory (like "Device" seems) followed by all the options that should be in a new screen (activity). All in only one screen.

Here are my files, thanks in advance

**Settings.java** (NOTE: Autogenerated and completed by myself)

```
package com.example;

import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.media.Ringtone;
import android.media.RingtoneManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.ListPreference;
import android.preference.Preference;
import android.preference.PreferenceActivity;
import android.preference.PreferenceCategory;
import android.preference.PreferenceFragment;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.preference.RingtonePreference;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.FutureTask;

/**
 * A {@link PreferenceActivity} that presents a set of application settings. On
 * handset devices, settings are presented as a single list. On tablets,
 * settings are split by category, with category headers shown to the left of
 * the list of settings.
 * <p>
 * See <a href="http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/settings.html">
 * Android Design: Settings</a> for design guidelines and the <a
 * href="http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings.html">Settings
 * API Guide</a> for more information on developing a Settings UI.
 */
public class Settings extends PreferenceActivity {
// From stackoverflow to avoid error API 19
protected boolean isValidFragment(String fragmentName) {
    if (ProfilePreferenceFragment.class.getName().equals(fragmentName)) {
        return true;
    } else if (ChatPreferenceFragment.class.getName().equals(fragmentName)) {
        return true;
    } else if (NotificationPreferenceFragment.class.getName().equals(
            fragmentName)) {
        return true;
    } else if (ContactPreferenceFragment.class.getName().equals(
            fragmentName)) {
        return true;
    } else if (PaymentPreferenceFragment.class.getName().equals(
            fragmentName)) {
        return true;
    } else if (AccessibilityPreferenceFragment.class.getName().equals(
            fragmentName)) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}// From stackoverflow to avoid error API 19

/**
 * Determines whether to always show the simplified settings UI, where
 * settings are presented in a single list. When false, settings are shown
 * as a master/detail two-pane view on tablets. When true, a single pane is
 * shown on tablets.
 */
private static final boolean ALWAYS_SIMPLE_PREFS = false;

@Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setupSimplePreferencesScreen();
}

/**
 * Shows the simplified settings UI if the device configuration
 * dictates that a simplified, single-pane UI should be
 * shown.
 */
private void setupSimplePreferencesScreen() {
    if (!isSimplePreferences(this)) {
        return;
    }

    // In the simplified UI, fragments are not used at all and we instead
    // use the older PreferenceActivity APIs.

    // Add 'profile' preferences.
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.pref_profile);

    // Add 'chats' preferences, and a corresponding header.
    PreferenceCategory fakeHeader = new PreferenceCategory(this);
    fakeHeader.setTitle(R.string.pref_header_chat);
    getPreferenceScreen().addPreference(fakeHeader);
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.pref_chat);

    // Add 'notification' preferences, and a corresponding header.
    fakeHeader = new PreferenceCategory(this);
    fakeHeader.setTitle(R.string.pref_header_notification);
    getPreferenceScreen().addPreference(fakeHeader);
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.pref_notification);

    // Add 'contact' preferences, and a corresponding header.
    fakeHeader = new PreferenceCategory(this);
    fakeHeader.setTitle(R.string.pref_header_contact);
    getPreferenceScreen().addPreference(fakeHeader);
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.pref_contact);

    // Add 'payment' preferences, and a corresponding header.
    fakeHeader = new PreferenceCategory(this);
    fakeHeader.setTitle(R.string.pref_header_payment);
    getPreferenceScreen().addPreference(fakeHeader);
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.pref_payment);

    // Add 'accessibility' preferences, and a corresponding header.
    fakeHeader = new PreferenceCategory(this);
    fakeHeader.setTitle(R.string.pref_header_accessibility);
    getPreferenceScreen().addPreference(fakeHeader);
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.pref_accesibility);

    // Bind the summaries of EditText/List/Dialog/Ringtone preferences to
    // their values. When their values change, their summaries are updated
    // to reflect the new value, per the Android Design guidelines.
    // bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(findPreference("example_text"));
    // bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(findPreference("example_list"));
    // bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(findPreference("notifications_new_message_ringtone"));
    // bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(findPreference("sync_frequency"));
}

/** {@inheritDoc} */
@Override
public boolean onIsMultiPane() {
    return isXLargeTablet(this) && !isSimplePreferences(this);
}

/**
 * Helper method to determine if the device has an extra-large screen. For
 * example, 10" tablets are extra-large.
 */
private static boolean isXLargeTablet(Context context) {
    return (context.getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout & Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK) >= Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_XLARGE;
}

/**
 * Determines whether the simplified settings UI should be shown. This is
 * true if this is forced via {@link #ALWAYS_SIMPLE_PREFS}, or the device
 * doesn't have newer APIs like {@link PreferenceFragment}, or the device
 * doesn't have an extra-large screen. In these cases, a single-pane
 * "simplified" settings UI should be shown.
 */
private static boolean isSimplePreferences(Context context) {
    return ALWAYS_SIMPLE_PREFS
            || Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB
            || !isXLargeTablet(context);
}

/** {@inheritDoc} */
@Override
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
public void onBuildHeaders(List<Header> target) {
    if (!isSimplePreferences(this)) {
        loadHeadersFromResource(R.xml.pref_headers, target);
    }
}

/**
 * A preference value change listener that updates the preference's summary
 * to reflect its new value.
 */
private static Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener sBindPreferenceSummaryToValueListener = new Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object value) {
        String stringValue = value.toString();

        if (preference instanceof ListPreference) {
            // For list preferences, look up the correct display value in
            // the preference's 'entries' list.
            ListPreference listPreference = (ListPreference) preference;
            int index = listPreference.findIndexOfValue(stringValue);

            // Set the summary to reflect the new value.
            preference
                    .setSummary(index >= 0 ? listPreference.getEntries()[index]
                            : null);

        } else if (preference instanceof RingtonePreference) {
            // For ringtone preferences, look up the correct display value
            // using RingtoneManager.
            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(stringValue)) {
                // Empty values correspond to 'silent' (no ringtone).

            } else {
                Ringtone ringtone = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(
                        preference.getContext(), Uri.parse(stringValue));

                if (ringtone == null) {
                    // Clear the summary if there was a lookup error.
                    preference.setSummary(null);
                } else {
                    // Set the summary to reflect the new ringtone display
                    // name.
                    String name = ringtone
                            .getTitle(preference.getContext());
                    preference.setSummary(name);
                }
            }

        } else {
            // For all other preferences, set the summary to the value's
            // simple string representation.
            preference.setSummary(stringValue);
        }
        return true;
    }
};

/**
 * Binds a preference's summary to its value. More specifically, when the
 * preference's value is changed, its summary (line of text below the
 * preference title) is updated to reflect the value. The summary is also
 * immediately updated upon calling this method. The exact display format is
 * dependent on the type of preference.
 * 
 * @see #sBindPreferenceSummaryToValueListener
 */
private static void bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(Preference preference) {
    // Set the listener to watch for value changes.
    preference
            .setOnPreferenceChangeListener(sBindPreferenceSummaryToValueListener);

    // Trigger the listener immediately with the preference's
    // current value.
    sBindPreferenceSummaryToValueListener.onPreferenceChange(
            preference,
            PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(
                    preference.getContext()).getString(preference.getKey(),
                    ""));
}

/**
 * This fragment shows profile preferences only. It is used when the
 * activity is showing a two-pane settings UI.
 */
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
public static class ProfilePreferenceFragment extends PreferenceFragment {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.pref_profile);

        // Bind the summaries of EditText/List/Dialog/Ringtone preferences
        // to their values. When their values change, their summaries are
        // updated to reflect the new value, per the Android Design
        // guidelines.
        // bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(findPreference(""));
        // bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(findPreference(""));
    }
}

/**
 * This fragment shows chat preferences only. It is used when the activity
 * is showing a two-pane settings UI.
 */
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
public static class ChatPreferenceFragment extends PreferenceFragment {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.pref_chat);

        // Bind the summaries of EditText/List/Dialog/Ringtone preferences
        // to their values. When their values change, their summaries are
        // updated to reflect the new value, per the Android Design
        // guidelines.
        bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(findPreference("pref_chat_enter_send"));
        bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(findPreference("pref_chat_download_message"));
        bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(findPreference("pref_chat_download_multimedia"));
        bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(findPreference("pref_chat_font_size"));
        bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(findPreference("pref_chat_wallpaper"));
        bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(findPreference("pref_chat_cloud"));
    }
}

/**
 * This fragment shows notification preferences only. It is used when the
 * activity is showing a two-pane settings UI.
 */
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
public static class NotificationPreferenceFragment extends
        PreferenceFragment {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.pref_notification);

        // Bind the summaries of EditText/List/Dialog/Ringtone preferences
        // to their values. When their values change, their summaries are
        // updated to reflect the new value, per the Android Design
        // guidelines.
        bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(findPreference("pref_notification_new_contact"));
        bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(findPreference("pref_notification_cat_individual_vibration"));
        bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(findPreference("pref_notification_cat_individual_vibration_repeat"));
        bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(findPreference("pref_notification_cat_individual_led"));
        bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(findPreference("pref_notification_cat_individual_led_repeat"));
        bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(findPreference("pref_notification_cat_individual_screen"));
        bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(findPreference("pref_notification_cat_individual_screen_repeat"));
        bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(findPreference("pref_notification_cat_group_vibration"));
        bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(findPreference("pref_notification_cat_group_vibration_repeat"));
        bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(findPreference("pref_notification_cat_group_led"));
        bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(findPreference("pref_notification_cat_group_led_repeat"));
        bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(findPreference("pref_notification_cat_group_screen"));
        bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(findPreference("pref_notification_cat_group_screen_repeat"));
    }
}

/**
 * This fragment shows contact preferences only. It is used when the
 * activity is showing a two-pane settings UI.
 */
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
public static class ContactPreferenceFragment extends PreferenceFragment {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.pref_contact);

        // Bind the summaries of EditText/List/Dialog/Ringtone preferences
        // to their values. When their values change, their summaries are
        // updated to reflect the new value, per the Android Design
        // guidelines.
        // bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(findPreference(""));
        // bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(findPreference(""));
    }
}

/**
 * This fragment shows payment preferences only. It is used when the
 * activity is showing a two-pane settings UI.
 */
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
public static class PaymentPreferenceFragment extends PreferenceFragment {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.pref_payment);

        // Bind the summaries of EditText/List/Dialog/Ringtone preferences
        // to their values. When their values change, their summaries are
        // updated to reflect the new value, per the Android Design
        // guidelines.
        // bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(findPreference(""));
        // bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(findPreference(""));
    }
}
}
```

**pref_headers.xml**

```
<preference-headers xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<!-- These settings headers are only used on tablets. -->

<header
    android:fragment="com.example.Settings$ProfilePreferenceFragment"
    android:title="@string/pref_header_profile" />
<header
    android:fragment="com.example.Settings$ChatPreferenceFragment"
    android:title="@string/pref_header_chat" />
<header
    android:fragment="com.example.Settings$NotificationPreferenceFragment"
    android:title="@string/pref_header_notification" />
<header
    android:fragment="com.example.Settings$ContactPreferenceFragment"
    android:title="@string/pref_header_contact" />
<header
    android:fragment="com.example.Settings$PaymentPreferenceFragment"
    android:title="@string/pref_header_payment" />

</preference-headers>
```

and one section example, others are like this. **pref_notification.xml**

```
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<SwitchPreference
    android:key="pref_notification_new_contact"
    android:summary="@string/pref_notification_new_contact_summary"
    android:title="@string/pref_notification_new_contact_title" />

<PreferenceCategory
    android:key="pref_notification_cat_individual"
    android:title="@string/pref_notification_cat_individual" >
    <SwitchPreference
        android:defaultValue="true"
        android:key="pref_notification_cat_individual_vibration"
        android:title="@string/pref_notification_cat_individual_vibration_title" />

    <CheckBoxPreference
        android:defaultValue="true"
        android:dependency="pref_notification_cat_individual_vibration"
        android:key="pref_notification_cat_individual_vibration_repeat"
        android:summary="@string/pref_notification_cat_individual_vibration_repeat_summary"
        android:title="@string/pref_notification_cat_individual_vibration_repeat" />

    <SwitchPreference
        android:defaultValue="true"
        android:key="pref_notification_cat_individual_led"
        android:title="@string/pref_notification_cat_individual_led_title" />

    <CheckBoxPreference
        android:defaultValue="true"
        android:dependency="pref_notification_cat_individual_led"
        android:key="pref_notification_cat_individual_led_repeat"
        android:summary="@string/pref_notification_cat_individual_led_repeat_summary"
        android:title="@string/pref_notification_cat_individual_led_repeat" />

    <SwitchPreference
        android:defaultValue="true"
        android:key="pref_notification_cat_individual_screen"
        android:title="@string/pref_notification_cat_individual_screen_title" />

    <CheckBoxPreference
        android:defaultValue="true"
        android:dependency="pref_notification_cat_individual_screen"
        android:key="pref_notification_cat_individual_screen_repeat"
        android:summary="@string/pref_notification_cat_individual_screen_repeat_summary"
        android:title="@string/pref_notification_cat_individual_screen_repeat" />
</PreferenceCategory>
<PreferenceCategory 
    android:key="pref_notification_cat_group"
    android:title="@string/pref_notification_cat_group" >
    <SwitchPreference
        android:defaultValue="true"
        android:key="pref_notification_cat_group_vibration"
        android:title="@string/pref_notification_cat_group_vibration_title" />

    <CheckBoxPreference
        android:defaultValue="true"
        android:dependency="pref_notification_cat_group_vibration"
        android:key="pref_notification_cat_group_vibration_repeat"
        android:summary="@string/pref_notification_cat_group_vibration_repeat_summary"
        android:title="@string/pref_notification_cat_group_vibration_repeat" />

    <SwitchPreference
        android:defaultValue="true"
        android:key="pref_notification_cat_group_led"
        android:title="@string/pref_notification_cat_group_led_title" />

    <CheckBoxPreference
        android:defaultValue="true"
        android:dependency="pref_notification_cat_group_led"
        android:key="pref_notification_cat_group_led_repeat"
        android:summary="@string/pref_notification_cat_group_led_repeat_summary"
        android:title="@string/pref_notification_cat_group_led_repeat" />

    <SwitchPreference
        android:defaultValue="true"
        android:key="pref_notification_cat_group_screen"
        android:title="@string/pref_notification_cat_group_screen_title" />

    <CheckBoxPreference
        android:defaultValue="true"
        android:dependency="pref_notification_cat_group_screen"
        android:key="pref_notification_cat_group_screen_repeat"
        android:summary="@string/pref_notification_cat_group_screen_repeat_summary"
        android:title="@string/pref_notification_cat_group_screen_repeat" />
</PreferenceCategory>

</PreferenceScreen>
```

Comment: Can you please put up links to the images of the desired output?